# Get the position of a node in a list?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I wonder how to find the position of one country in CoronaVirus update list https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus  by using Chrome console

I tried: `$x("count(.//*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody/tr/td[1][.='Vietnam']/preceding-sibling::*)")`

[image]

Anyone could give me a light here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xpath you are applying `preciding-siblings` to the first `td` in a `tr`, but you should count siblings for `tr` as those are actually the rows.

This one worked for me:

```
$x("count(//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//tr[td/text() = 'Vietnam']/preceding-sibling::*)")
```

Also in my opinion there is no need to do `+1` at the end as the first row is irrelevant: the whole world. But you should know better, what you need.

[image]

Or here is yours fixed:

```
$x("count(.//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody/tr[td[1][.='Vietnam']]/preceding-sibling::*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete kishkin's answer, shortest form :

```
count((//td[.='Vietnam'])[1]/preceding::tr[@style=""])+1
```

Output  : 93 (92+1)

And to exclude the Diamond Princess :

```
count((//td[.='Vietnam'])[1]/preceding::tr[@style=""][not(.//span)])+1
```

Output : 92 (91+1)